# Site got an error after moving from local to a server

Tags: 8, debugging

I finally wanted to move my site from localhost. After importing db and connecting it to the Drupal I got these errors:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
>   error or access violation: 1142 INSERT command denied to user
>   'bpcoders_44'@'10.254.34.28' for table 'watchdog': INSERT INTO
>   {watchdog} (uid, type, message, variables, severity, link, location,
>   referer, hostname, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_9); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 0
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => DrupalKernel [:db_insert_placeholder_2]
>   => Container cannot be saved to cache. [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => a:0:{} [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 3 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] =>
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => [:db_insert_placeholder_7] =>
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 1465229026
>   ) in Drupal\dblog\Logger\DbLog->log() (line 79 of
>   core/modules/dblog/src/Logger/DbLog.php).
>   Drupal\dblog\Logger\DbLog->log(3, 'Container cannot be saved to
>   cache.', Array) (Line: 104) Drupal\dblog\Logger\DbLog->log(3,
>   'Container cannot be saved to cache.', Array) (Line: 136)
>   Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannel->log('error', 'Container cannot be
>   saved to cache.', Array) (Line: 66)
>   Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannel->error('Container cannot be saved to
>   cache.') (Line: 869) Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer()
>   (Line: 437) Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 627)
>   Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

How can I fix it? Do I need to contact hosting support?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/requirements/database

Comment: My MySql version seems to be fine: 5.5.40

Comment: Quote: "Drupal makes use of some features not available on some inexpensive hosting plans so please check that your host allows database accounts with the following rights:
SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER."

Comment: Notice that you are just exposing facts without asking any explicit question. Stack Exchange doesn't work well with implicit questions.

Answer (score 1):

The database user you specified in settings.php does not have INSERT privileges on the watchdog table. Contact your hosting provider support.